DORIS: How to perform streaming queries using http protocol through DORIS REST API?
I want to query the data inside doris through http protocol, but because the data is too large, I have to use streaming query
Now I am using the 8030 port of DORIS for query, which obviously cannot achieve the results I expected.
By the way, how about using PyMysql to directly connect to Doris' 9030 port?

Pasting the answer from the Apache Doris GitHub repo here: Maybe you can try spark-doris-connector for massive data import and export.
